# LaTeX verbatim environment inside lists

Tags: lists, environments, verbatim

I am using LaTeX and I have a verbatim environment inside an enumerate one. However, there is much whitespace between the verbatim text and the following list item.

What I have now is something like this:
[image: Incorrect]

**I would like to get something like this:**
[image: Correct]

Does anyone know how to achieve it in an elegant way (i.e. without manually using `\vspace{-4ex}`)?

**[EDIT]** The code I am using is like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
        dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta. Morbi arcu nibh, consequat
        non consequat a, congue sed libero.
        \begin{verbatim}
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            Vestibulum dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta.
        \end{verbatim}

    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
        dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta. Morbi arcu nibh, consequat
        non consequat a, congue sed libero.
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! I took the liberty to remove the `{latex}` tag from your question because most of the questions at our site are about LaTeX.

Comment: Could you give us a minimal example so that we know what your code looks like?

Comment: @meep.meep: Done

Comment: Many newbies uses verbatim unnecessarily, and it's typically very rarely the best choice. If you are just looking for the font style, then you should use `\texttt{...}`. If its describing code, then using listings is preferable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seem to be that the `verbatim` environment is indented. Note that the spaces at the beginning are also taken verbatim. Do not indent it and use e.g. the `quote` environment for an extra indention in the resulting document if this is wanted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
        dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta. Morbi arcu nibh, consequat
        non consequat a, congue sed libero.
        \begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta.
\end{verbatim}
        \end{quote}

    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
        dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta. Morbi arcu nibh, consequat
        non consequat a, congue sed libero.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. That works. The problem seems that when there is whitespace before `\end{verbatim}`, LaTeX supposes it is a blank line. The use of the quote environment is awesome. (I am really sorry, but I can't mark this answer as useful since I don't have enough reputation).

Answer (score 2):

You use too many spaces every line :)

The *vertical* space around `verbatim` environment can be reduced like lists. Note that a `verbatim` environment itself is a list. Say you can use something like:

```
\begingroup
\topsep=0pt
\itemsep=0pt
\begin{verbatim}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta.
\end{verbatim}
```

However, the space before and after `verbatim` comes from both `verbatim` and `enumerate`, you may want to reduce both of them. This can be done by `enumitem` package, for both together. And you can use `fancyvrb` package to add the left margin. Here is full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
        dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta. Morbi arcu nibh, consequat
        non consequat a, congue sed libero.
\begin{Verbatim}[xleftmargin=2em]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Vestibulum dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta.
\end{Verbatim}
    \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
        dictum quam at sapien pellentesque porta. Morbi arcu nibh, consequat
        non consequat a, congue sed libero.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]